# How to add text on top of an image in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I want to know how to add text on to of an image in tkinter. I type in the following code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
draw=ImageDraw.Draw("maybe.png")
pixellat=ImageFont.truetype("pixellat.ttf",18)
draw.text((125, 125),"This is a test",(255,255,255),font=pixellat)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 344, in Draw
return im.getdraw(mode)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Apple/Desktop/pong 1.2/pong menu.py", line 41, in <module>
draw=ImageDraw.Draw("maybe.png")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 346, in Draw
return ImageDraw(im, mode)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 60, in __init__
im.load()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Can you help me fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open/load the image first... like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Open input image
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')

# Get a drawing context
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

pixellat=ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Apple Chancery.ttf",48)
draw.text((80, 40),"This is a test",(255,255,255),font=pixellat)

# Save
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]