# Is there a way to draw the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" symbol on an image using cv2 or PIL in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I am trying to draw the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, �, ASCII value:65533, in an image as a text element by using Open CV2 or ImageDraw, but it always adds the NOT A CHARACTER, , ASCII value:65533, on the image instead. I have even validated that I am creating the correct character but to no success.

Is there any way to add the �  to an image using a specific font size, adding it as text?

Comment: `ASCII` has only values 0 to 127. Value `65533` is not asci code.

Comment: that isn't true, you are able to draw character symbols of that value. Try print out print(str(chr(65533))) and you will see

Comment: Python 3 uses Unicode in `chr()` but maybe OpenCV uses only ASCII codes. But if you run it in Python 2 you get `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: I am running on python 3, and as you can see here. the symbol does have an ASCII value [link](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/65533/replacement-character_

Comment: it is not ASCII but only decimal value for unicode U+FFFD. Try `hex(65533)` and you get value `'0xfffd'`. And here is text from Wikipedia [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) - `"Originally based on the English alphabet, ASCII encodes 128 specified characters into seven-bit integers"`

Comment: BTW: if you try to write `chr(65533)` with `ascii` encoding - ie. `open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='ascii').write(chr(65533))` then you get error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Thanks @furas So I guess it just isn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Open image with OpenCV
im_o = cv2.imread('start.png')

# Make into PIL Image
im_p = Image.fromarray(im_o)

# Get a drawing context
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_p)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf",32)
draw.text((40, 20),"What character  �",(255,255,255),font=font)

# Convert back to OpenCV image and save
result_o = np.array(im_p)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result_o)
```

[image]

Note that PIL and OpenCV use different ordering for their colour channels, i.e. RGB vs BGR, so you do need to pay attention to this - unless annotating in black, white or green like I do here. There is some more discussion and an easy way to work around this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697181/2836621).