# How to draw arabic text on the video using `cv2.putText`correctly? (Python+OpenCV)

Tags: python, csv, opencv

I use Python cv2 (windows 10, python3.6) to read a text an `csv` to play it on video, when the text is English it works, but when I use Arabic text it writes "???"

My code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("n.mp4")
# Initiate holistic model
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    
        # Recolor Feed
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False        
    
        # Make Detections
        results = holistic.process(image)
        # print(results.face_landmarks)
    
        # face_landmarks, pose_landmarks, left_hand_landmarks, right_hand_landmarks
    
        # Recolor image back to BGR for rendering
        image.flags.writeable = True   
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
        # 1. Draw face landmarks
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACE_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,110,10), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,256,121), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                             )
    
        # 2. Right hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             )

        # 3. Left Hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,22,76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,44,250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             )

        # 4. Pose Detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS, 
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                             mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                             )
        # Export coordinates
        try:
            # Extract Pose landmarks
            pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())
        
            # Extract Face landmarks
            face = results.face_landmarks.landmark
            face_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in face]).flatten())
        
            # Concate rows
            row = pose_row+face_row
        


            # Make Detections
            X = pd.DataFrame([row])
            body_language_class = model.predict(X)[0]
            body_language_prob = model.predict_proba(X)[0]
            print(body_language_class, body_language_prob)
        
        
        
            # Grab ear coords
            coords = tuple(np.multiply(
                            np.array(
                            (results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_holistic.PoseLandmark.LEFT_EAR].x, 
                             results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_holistic.PoseLandmark.LEFT_EAR].y))
                    , [640,480]).astype(int))
        
            cv2.rectangle(image, 
                      (coords[0], coords[1]+5), 
                      (coords[0]+len(body_language_class)*20, coords[1]-30), 
                      (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, body_language_class, coords, 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        
            # Get status box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (0,0), (250, 60), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, 'CLASS'
                    , (95,12), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, body_language_class.split(' ')[0]
                    , (90,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        
            # Display Probability
            cv2.putText(image, 'PROB'
                    , (15,12), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(round(body_language_prob[np.argmax(body_language_prob)],2))
                    , (10,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        
        except:
            pass
                    
        cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't know if OpenCV's minimalist text-rendering and fonts are able to do arabic. If not, I made an answer here that shows a way of using other fonts... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697181/2836621 Note that `wand` is also almost certainly able to do this too... https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/

Comment: Note that if you just have a limited number of annotations/labels, you could generate them all *"up-front"* on pieces of canvas like I show in the linked answer then put them onto your video at run-time with `cv2.addWeighted()` or similar.