# How can I add a font on OpenCV library in python?

Tags: python, opencv, fonts

I have a very specific question to ask regarding fonts on `OpenCV`.

As well known, the fonts are predefined, and if you want to use fonts that are not in the list, you need the help of PIL(`Pillow`).

Now my problem is that `Pillow` allows to do some operations with a font, but for example it doesn't allow to calculate its height which I need.

So I have a doubt, if the `OpenCV` library has a list of fonts available it is possible to add one to the list.

To explain myself better, I think the Hershey fonts it uses are somewhere, I don't know if in a file or elsewhere.
So the possibility of modifying the library and adding one doesn't seem so remote to me (Maybe I'm wrong).

I know the question is very specific and maybe not possible to answer, but I would appreciate any kind of help or critique of my question that could point me in the right direction.

Plus I want to ask as a last question in case there is no answer to the first.
There is a font management library fully compatible with this syntax on `OpenCV` that allows me to replace fontFace with another font:

`cv2.putText(img=white_back, text=text, org=(bl[0], bl[1] - 10), fontFace="FONT_NOT_HERSHEY", fontScale=font_scale, color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=thickness, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697181/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly add a font to the list of fonts available in the OpenCV library. The Hershey fonts used by OpenCV are internally defined and cannot be easily modified or extended.

However, if you need to use a specific font that is not available in OpenCV, you can use the combination of OpenCV and Pillow (PIL) libraries to achieve your desired result. Here's a step-by-step approach to accomplish this:

Install the necessary libraries:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install Pillow
```

Locate the TrueType font file **(.ttf)** of the font you want to use. Ensure you have the rights to use the font in your application.

Use Pillow to load the font and perform necessary operations such as calculating the font height. For example, to calculate the font height:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

font_path = "path_to_your_font.ttf"
font_size = 24

font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)
font_height = font.getsize("A")[1]  # Calculate the height using a sample character
```

Use OpenCV to draw text on an image using the loaded font. You can specify the font, size, color, etc.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)  # Example image

text = "Hello, World!"
color = (255, 255, 255)  # White color
position = (50, 50)  # Position to draw the text

image_pil = Image.fromarray(image)  # Convert OpenCV image to PIL image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_pil)
draw.text(position, text, font=font, fill=color)
image_with_text = np.array(image_pil)  # Convert PIL image back to OpenCV image

cv2.imshow("Image with Text", image_with_text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*By combining OpenCV and Pillow, you can use any TrueType font and perform various operations like calculating font height, drawing text, and more.
Please note that modifying the internal font list of OpenCV is not a recommended approach as it would require modifying the source code and recompiling the library, which can be complex and not practical for most use cases. Using the above method with Pillow is a more flexible and easier solution.*

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom fonts using freetype2 in opencv. You might have to install opencv using conda or build it from source with freetype support.
(pip install does not seem to work)

Refer:

- https://fireant.github.io/misc/2017/01/28/ttf-opencv.html
- [Load TrueType Font to OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv)